# link an Excel cell from an embedded document in Word

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

I have a Word document with an Excel document embedded. I would like to show some values from the Excel in the Word document. Of course they have to get updated when the Excel changes. I know how to do this for an external Excel worksheet, but I did not find a way to do this for my embedded one. I am using Office 2010.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the only way this works is if you use .doc format, and even then it may not be completely reliable. Otherwise, the problem is that Word references the existing embedded Excel object using an ID that (a) Word changes when you save or re-open the .docx and (b) that you cannot discover using the Word Object Model. So you can't even "fix up" the references using VBA.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't always work, but once I used `Tools->Insert>Object(excel)`